# Deploying Play! 2.4 and Database Evolutions

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean, playframework-evolutions

I am trying to deploy and run a Play! 2.4 project on a server.

```
sudo bin/app -Dhttp.port=80 -Dconfig.resource=production.conf -DapplyEvolutions.default=true
```

The source code I have deployed on the server (and from which I run stage) however does not contain the evolution SQL scripts. Should I build them, and include them, at the development stage, or is there a way that they generate themselves either at build stage or at the start of the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope they don't generate themselves. You write them, and usually store them in `conf/evolutions/default` (or alternative db name). [More information here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Evolutions). They are managed with the rest of the source code.

There are some discussions about this in other SO questions such as [Managing evolutions in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314720/managing-evolutions-in-production-environment)